# Data on Lobbying Expenditures: Net Neutrality

Tags: data-request, usa, government

I found this really interesting graph at sunlightfoundation.com.

[image]

I would like to do one of my own, just with a few style tweaks and updated for 2018, or at least 2017. I checked the source's website, but found no raw data there. Perhaps by "source" they meant they were the ones who put the graph together? I would imagine they must have got their numbers from *somewhere*.

**Question:** Is there an open resource for lobbying expenditures? I presume I could then narrow the selection down by topic. I am basically only interested in Net Neutrality lobbying data at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they used data from OpenSecrets. Access to their data is available at https://www.opensecrets.org/open-data.

> Mentions of net neutrality in lobbying reports, 2005-2013; Sunlight Foundation using OpenSecrets.org data

[OpenSecrets](https://www.opensecrets.org/news/issues/net_neutrality/)